# Unable to validate a JWT token created in a Spring app using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, spring, jwt

I have an authentication microservice developed using Java, Spring. In this service, a simple JWT is created. Here is the JWT class:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String APP_SECRET;

    @Value("${jwt.expiresIn}")
    private long EXPIRES_IN;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication auth) {
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        Date expireDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + EXPIRES_IN);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(Long.toString(userDetails.getId()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expireDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, APP_SECRET)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(APP_SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return !isTokenExpired(token);
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And, here is my 256-bit secret key in the application.properties file, which is created using [this generator](https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/plain).

```
# JWT
jwt.secret=92502665b0711fc987959b89d3958a26b2f8f60a8963263360192b89e7c0fa44
jwt.expiresIn=604800
```

When I try, it can be easily validated in the Spring app. However, in the NodeJS service, I cannot verify and get the payload of the provided JWTs. **`jsonwebtoken` always returns `Invalid Signature` error.**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const getAccessToRoute = (req, res, next) => {
    const { JWT_SECRET_KEY } = process.env;

    if (!isTokenIncluded(req)) {
        // return token not found
    }

    // extract the token from header
    const accessToken = getAccessTokenFromHeader(req);

    jwt.verify(accessToken, JWT_SECRET_KEY, async (err, decodedUserInfos) => {
        console.log("DECODED USER INFOS", decodedUserInfos); // undefined
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid or expired token" })
        }

        req.loggedUser = {
            id: decodedUserInfos.id,
        };

        next();
    })
};
```

And here is the jwt secret in .env file:

```
# JWT
JWT_SECRET_KEY=92502665b0711fc987959b89d3958a26b2f8f60a8963263360192b89e7c0fa44
```

Secret keys and signing algorithms are the same in both services. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution.

JsonWebToken library on the Java side requires a base64 encoded secret key. Here is the method signature from `Jwts` class:

```
JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, String base64EncodedSecretKey) throws InvalidKeyException;
```

But in my case, I provided a plain 256-bit random key. So the solution is either making your secret key base64 encoded or decoding your secret key using Buffer on the NodeJS side:

```
const decodedBase64 = Buffer.from(JWT_SECRET_KEY, 'base64')

jwt.verify(accessToken, decodedBase64, async (err, decodedUserInfos) => {
    // ...
})
```

I go with simply encoding the key with base64:

```
# JWT
jwt.secret=ZTdhYWViOTNkOWUzOGI0M2Q2YWNjYTE5MmE3NmJhYjIyNTFmN2UwNzIwNThhN2NlZThjMmQyMTE4MGRkMWYzOQ==
```